# How to restrict Gmail API access to a smaller perimeter

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

Currently, I followed GSuite tutorial to get access for my app to a client company's email. It works following the "Server Side Authorizaton" flow.

I would like to restrict access rights of my app to a specific group of users from my client, so my client doesn't have to give access to ALL users of his organization.

Where can we set this perimeter ?

Comment: Does the app register as a marketplace app in the Admin Console?

Comment: @ScottMcC, I am deploying the app without being published on the marketplace yet. So configuration is based on two steps for my customer : 1) Activate GMail Api and Admin SDK Api. 2) In Admin Console > Security > Advanced parameters > Manage API Client access --> add the id of my app and relevant scopes. But nowhere to restreign the right to a specific organizational unit or group.